# HowTo: Add Jobs To cron Under Linux or UNIX?

Tags: php, linux

how can i in woke PHP script file which is creating mysql db backup om server using LINUX.
[image]

it tried following

```
/public_html/db-export.php
/db-exoprt.php
db-exoprt.php
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: Log in to a command line interface, run the script manually and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`php -f 'path/to/file.php'`

The -f flag signals you want to execute a file.